# Query database and group by week's monday

Tags: sql, date, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a large database with this fields

```
date         sku    sales
2019-02-23   123    20
2019-02-24   123    33
2019-02-25   123    45
2019-02-20   456    15
2019-02-22   456    23
```

And I would like to get the total SALES PER WEEK but the tricky part is that I need to assume that the earliest date from each SKU is a monday so the table should look like this:

```
date         sku    sales
2019-02-18   123    20
2019-02-19   123    33
2019-02-20   123    45
2019-02-18   456    15
2019-02-20   456    23
```

Expected result should be:

```
date         sku    sales
W1           123    98
W1           456    38
```

- SKUs with more than 7 days should GROUP BY W1 and W2

So now I can GROUP BY week as all sales of sku 123 would fall the same week. Now In the case of a SKU with more that 7 days of sales the 8th day will be a monday again after conversion. In effect what I want is to add up sales but PRIOR to this assume that the earliest date for every SKU is the first monday of that week (shift the date by as many days as it would need to make the first record a monday. One possible issue is that records are not sorted by the corresponding field.

Thx!

Comment: Please tag the question with the RDBMS that you are using : mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: This is quite unclear to me. I understand that your sample data is the first table. Would you please show your expected result as well ?

Comment: Added expected result

Comment: would be great if in your input and output example you show data for multiple (at least 3 weeks) so it better is understood how you want to apply shifting logic. Also what is the real use-case / motivation behind such a logic. it looks unusual

Comment: Why does `sku` `456` belong to `W2`, while it as dates on `2019-02-20` and `2019-02-22`?

Comment: My bad should also be W1 already corrected

Comment: Are you just looking at grouping sales by `WEEK` by `SKU` with a week being defined as MONDAY -> SUNDAY (as opposed to SUNDAY -> SATURDAY)?

Comment: Yes week defined as Monday thru Sunday

Comment: Can't test in bigquery but you can calculate Monday's date from SkuDate with something like DATE_ADD(DATE '2019-01-07', INTERVAL (DATE_DIFF(DATE SkuDate, DATE '2019-01-07', DAY)/7)*7 DAY), then group by that. The '2019-01-07' date is some Monday in the past, could be 100 years ago or whatever is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CONCAT('W', CAST(DIV(DATE_DIFF(t.date, start_date, DAY) + 7, 7) AS STRING)) `date`,
  sku, 
  SUM(sales) sales
FROM `project.dataset.table` t JOIN (
  SELECT sku, MIN(t.date) AS start_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY sku
) s USING(sku)
GROUP BY sku, `date`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from  your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-23' `date`, '123' sku, 20 sales UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-24', '123', 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-25', '123', 45 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-20', '456', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-22', '456', 23 
)
SELECT 
  CONCAT('W', CAST(DIV(DATE_DIFF(t.date, start_date, DAY) + 7, 7) AS STRING)) `date`,
  sku, 
  SUM(sales) sales
FROM `project.dataset.table` t JOIN (
  SELECT sku, MIN(t.date) AS start_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY sku
) s USING(sku)
GROUP BY sku, `date`
-- ORDER BY sku, `date`
```

with result

```
Row     date    sku     sales    
1       W1      123     98   
2       W1      456     38
```